# Google Scripts: Generating a Reference ID after form submission

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I am sure there is an extremely simple answer to this, I have a google form for raising a trouble ticket, when this form is submitted it sends a notification email to the relevant parties. Within the subject line I need to create a unique ID number based on the row number, I have this working but cannot get the number to format correctly.

For example, the below code is generating "STAR1" but I am trying to generate "STAR0001". I am sure this is simple but I cannot get it to work.

`var star = sheet.getLastRow()-1;`

I tried the following but it will not run:

```
var starr = sheet.getLastRow()-1;
var star = starr.setNumberFormat("0000");
```

Apologies if this is staring me in the face but I just cannot get it to work, any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers,

Alex

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate strings.

```
var theLastRow = sheet.getLastRow()-1;
var uniqueID = "Star" + "0000" + theLastRow.toString();
```

If you need the leading zeros to be of different lengths, then you'll need to test for the length of the row number.

```
var lastRowLngth = theLastRow.toString().length;
Logger.log(lastRowLngth);
```